# AJAX async call will not update the control with data

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I ran the code below using a non async call the control jqStatusID is updated with data but if I use a Async call it won't update. Fiddler2 shows me that the data is coming okay. Why is that?
Do i Need to do a refresh on the control or something?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  //Function2(true); //no errors, data comes in but jqStatusID is NOT updated
  Function2(false);  //works great
});

function Function2(async)
{
  $.ajax
  ({
    async: async
    , url: "svc/JobViewer.svc/JobViewer/GetStatusList"
    , cache: false
    , dataType: "json"
    , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert("Get Status List ajax error:\r\n" + errorThrown)
    }
    , success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      $.each(data, function (key, value)
      {
        $(jqStatusID).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.StatusID).text(value.Name));
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Any ideas? thank you!

Comment: where is defined 'jqStatusID' ??? are you tried debug the js? I have the slight feeling, the problem is with the selector...

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to consider using `.val(value.StatusId)` rather than `.attr("value", value.StatusID)`. That's what it's for, after all.

Comment: Well, why doing a sync call works then? :( here is all code related to that control:

//markup
<select id="Status" style="width:205px" multiple="multiple"></select>

    var jqStatusID                    = "#Status"
    $(jqStatusID).multiselect({ noneSelectedText: "Select Job Status", selectedList: 2, minWidth: "auto" });

Comment: gee... the answer was in my own question! After I refreshed the control the data showed up duh: